# How to know correct or suitable tags to my question?

Tags: support, tags

It will be good always to see quick response in the form of answers and comments from the community. But how to know correct or suitable tags to my question for quick and suitable people attraction to my question as those tags play a vital role to reach suitable people to answer my question.

Comment: adding unrelated tags is not the right way.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and comment as well as for the -1. But it would be much appreciated, instead of doing the above things if one of those would have answered it suggesting or guiding new users. Sorry to say here all focusing on rep and earning badges or something like that instead of encouraging and guiding new users.

Comment: I didn't downvote you. I will post a detailed answer later when I've some free time - right now I'm at work & bit swamped to compose a decent answer. (as for your "should focus on encouraging and guiding new users instead of rep comment" - you have no idea how many comments/edits I (and several  others, if the edit queues & comments are any indication) have done suggesting what to do and what not do, majority of which get ignored   even after repeated attempts. You get jaded after repeating the same thing to which no one seemingly pays attention to, yet I carry on. Don't jump to conclusions)

Comment: No one earns or loses rep on Meta sites. And your question was probably downvoted because you spammed it with a bunch of unrelated tags. It's OK to ask for help though, and I'm sure someone is jumping on that as we speak. You only posted the question 30 minutes ago... Have a bit of patience, we're all volunteers here.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not going to duplicate information here. Similar to Super User Meta, there's a Meta for the whole Stack Exchange engine, called Meta Stack Overflow. You'll want to read this question there:

> #### [How do I correctly tag my questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions)

The gist of it is:

- **Choose at least one or two good matching tags.**  Those are the ones that are most frequently used. At the very least, choose [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows) or [linux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux) (etc.) for your operating system, if you're looking for practical solutions to a problem.
- Check out the [**most popular tags**](https://superuser.com/tags), and see if they fit. Popular tags have more followers, thus your question will probably be highlighted for them.
- Use **broader tags** if your question applies to this general tag. You don't necessarily have to tag your question [ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu) if it's about something that is the same in all [linux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux) distributions. However if your question only applies to [ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu), I would add both tags (or just the specific one).

And please remember:

- **Do not** compose tags. For example, [virtual](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/virtual) [machine](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/machine) is not the same as [virtual-machine](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/virtual-machine). The latter is what we want, not the first.
- **Do not** add too many tags. They won't help getting more views, and dilute the scope of these other tags. Especially, do **not add unrelated tags**.
- **Do not** create new tags unless there's a good reason to.
- **Do not** use [meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Answer (score 1):

Might also be more of a "how do I know which tags to use when I can't see the list of tags right in front of me'
If so:
Type 'a' (in the tag entry area) and look at the tags, if any seem good pick them.
Now try with 'b'.
and so on.
You'll probably get to 5 quickly (watch out for dupes).

Comment: Except it doesn't work that way. When typing `a`, the choices presented on the main site are: `windows-7`, `osx`, `mac`, `wireless-networking`, `hard-drive`, `windows-vista`. For `c`, it also suggests  `osx` and `mac`, for `d`, it presents `windows-7`, `windows`, `windows-xp`, `hard-drive`, `windows-vista`, `command-line`.

Comment: It looks like it's about three actual suggestions per letter, maybe less...